# ffmpeg determine correct codec to use

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I am trying to use `.y4m` files that I feed into Chrome for playing.
*This is the only format that I can use.*

I have a set of `.y4m` files that are working for my use case, taken from [here](http://media.xiph.org/video/derf/y4m/?C=N;O=A).
For example let's say that I use the file [mobile_qcif_7.5fps.y4m](http://media.xiph.org/video/derf/y4m/mobile_qcif_7.5fps.y4m).

I also have a `.mp4` file (specifically the sample [`small.mp4`](http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4) file from [techslides](http://techslides.com/sample-webm-ogg-and-mp4-video-files-for-html5) ). I know how to convert `small.mp4` to `small.y4m` with the following command :

`ffmpeg -y -i small.mp4 small.y4m`

I would like the resulting file to be accepted by Chrome, just like the other file.
What options should I use (and how to find them) ?

**Additional information**

**`ffprobe`** gives :

```
$ ffprobe small.y4m 
avprobe version 0.8.13-6:0.8.13-0ubuntu0.13.10.1, Copyright (c) 2007-2014 the Libav developers
  built on Jul 15 2014 13:48:35 with gcc 4.8.1
[yuv4mpegpipe @ 0x23160c0] Estimating duration from bitrate, this may be inaccurate
Input #0, yuv4mpegpipe, from 'small.y4m':
  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0.0: Video: rawvideo, yuv420p, 560x320, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 30 tbn, 30 tbc


$ ffprobe mobile_qcif_7.5fps.y4m
avprobe version 0.8.13-6:0.8.13-0ubuntu0.13.10.1, Copyright (c) 2007-2014 the Libav developers
  built on Jul 15 2014 13:48:35 with gcc 4.8.1
[yuv4mpegpipe @ 0x1e080c0] max_analyze_duration reached
[yuv4mpegpipe @ 0x1e080c0] Estimating duration from bitrate, this may be inaccurate
Input #0, yuv4mpegpipe, from 'mobile_qcif_7.5fps.y4m':
  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0.0: Video: rawvideo, yuv420p, 176x144, PAR 128:117 DAR 1408:1053, 7.50 fps, 7.50 tbr, 7.50 tbn, 7.50 tbc
```

**OS** : I am using ffmpeg in Ubuntu 13.10 from the default repository : I ran `sudo apt-get install ffmpeg libavcodec-extra-53`

**Complete console output**

```
$ ffmpeg -y -i small.mp4 small.y4m
ffmpeg version 0.8.13-6:0.8.13-0ubuntu0.13.10.1, Copyright (c) 2000-2014 the Libav developers
  built on Jul 15 2014 13:48:35 with gcc 4.8.1
*** THIS PROGRAM IS DEPRECATED ***
This program is only provided for compatibility and will be removed in a future release. Please use avconv instead.
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'small.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: mp42isomavc1
    creation_time   : 2010-03-20 21:29:11
    encoder         : HandBrake 0.9.4 2009112300
  Duration: 00:00:05.56, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 551 kb/s
    Stream #0.0(und): Video: h264 (Constrained Baseline), yuv420p, 560x320, 465 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 90k tbn, 60 tbc
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2010-03-20 21:29:11
    Stream #0.1(eng): Audio: aac, 48000 Hz, mono, s16, 83 kb/s
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2010-03-20 21:29:11
[buffer @ 0x7274e0] w:560 h:320 pixfmt:yuv420p
Output #0, yuv4mpegpipe, to 'small.y4m':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: mp42isomavc1
    creation_time   : 2010-03-20 21:29:11
    encoder         : Lavf53.21.1
    Stream #0.0(und): Video: rawvideo, yuv420p, 560x320, q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 90k tbn, 30 tbc
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2010-03-20 21:29:11
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0.0 -> #0.0
Press ctrl-c to stop encoding
frame=  166 fps=  0 q=0.0 Lsize=   43576kB time=5.53 bitrate=64513.5kbits/s    
video:0kB audio:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead inf%
```

**Head of the files**

Not sure if this is relevant, but the text content of both files begin like that :

```
mobile_qcif_7.5fps.y4m
YUV4MPEG2 W176 H144 F15:2 Ip A128:117
FRAME

small.y4m (invalid)
YUV4MPEG2 W560 H320 F15:2 Ip A0:0 C420mpeg2 XYSCSS=420MPEG2
FRAME
```

**Additional experiment**

Taking the sample `mobile_qcif_7.5fps.y4m`, turning it into a `.mp4` file and then back into a `.y4m` produces an invalid file (at least for Chrome).

**Answer to comments in the answer of @SirDarius**

Following the suggestion of @SirDarius; I tried the following commands.
They failed to produce a valid file.

```
# [COMMAND]   # [RESULT] [HEADER]
ffmpeg -i small.mp4 -vf fps=7.5 -an -c:v rawvideo -f yuv4mpegpipe -pix_fmt yuv444p -y small_yuv444p.y4m   # KO YUV4MPEG2 W560 H320 F15:2 Ip A0:0 C444 XYSCSS=444
ffmpeg -i small.mp4 -vf fps=7.5 -an -c:v rawvideo -f yuv4mpegpipe -pix_fmt yuv422p -y small_yuv422p.y4m   # KO YUV4MPEG2 W560 H320 F15:2 Ip A0:0 C422 XYSCSS=422
ffmpeg -i small.mp4 -vf fps=7.5 -an -c:v rawvideo -f yuv4mpegpipe -pix_fmt yuv420p -y small_yuv420p.y4m   # KO YUV4MPEG2 W560 H320 F15:2 Ip A0:0 C420mpeg2 XYSCSS=420MPEG2
ffmpeg -i small.mp4 -vf fps=7.5 -an -c:v rawvideo -f yuv4mpegpipe -pix_fmt yuv411p -y small_yuv411p.y4m   # KO   YUV4MPEG2 W560 H320 F15:2 Ip A0:0 C411 XYSCSS=411

ffmpeg -i small.mp4 -vf fps=7.5 -an -c:v rawvideo -f yuv4mpegpipe -strict -1 -pix_fmt yuv420p9 -y small_yuv420p9.y4m   # KO YUV4MPEG2 W560 H320 F15:2 Ip A0:0 C420p9 XYSCSS=420P9
ffmpeg -i small.mp4 -vf fps=7.5 -an -c:v rawvideo -f yuv4mpegpipe -strict -1 -pix_fmt yuv420p12 -y small_yuv420p12.y4m # KO YUV4MPEG2 W560 H320 F15:2 Ip A0:0 C420p12 XYSCSS=420P12
ffmpeg -i small.mp4 -vf fps=7.5 -an -c:v rawvideo -f yuv4mpegpipe -strict -1 -pix_fmt yuv420p14 -y small_yuv420p14.y4m # KO YUV4MPEG2 W560 H320 F15:2 Ip A0:0 C420p14 XYSCSS=420P14
ffmpeg -i small.mp4 -vf fps=7.5 -an -c:v rawvideo -f yuv4mpegpipe -strict -1 -pix_fmt yuv420p16 -y small_yuv420p16.y4m # KO YUV4MPEG2 W560 H320 F15:2 Ip A0:0 C420p16 XYSCSS=420P16
```

When trying other formats (like `yuv420p12be`, which was in the output of `-pix_fmts`), I had the following output (hence my previous trials) :

```
$  ffmpeg -i small.mp4 -vf fps=7.5 -an -c:v rawvideo -f yuv4mpegpipe -pix_fmt yuv420p12be -y small_yuv420p12be.y4m 
ffmpeg version N-68884-g3ebd76a Copyright (c) 2000-2015 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Jan  6 2015 11:03:21 with gcc 4.8 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.8.1-10ubuntu9)
  configuration: 
  libavutil      54. 16.100 / 54. 16.100
  libavcodec     56. 19.100 / 56. 19.100
  libavformat    56. 18.100 / 56. 18.100
  libavdevice    56.  3.100 / 56.  3.100
  libavfilter     5.  6.100 /  5.  6.100
  libswscale      3.  1.101 /  3.  1.101
  libswresample   1.  1.100 /  1.  1.100
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x21d0220] overread end of atom 'colr' by 1 bytes
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'small.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: mp42isomavc1
    creation_time   : 2010-03-20 21:29:11
    encoder         : HandBrake 0.9.4 2009112300
  Duration: 00:00:05.57, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 551 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Constrained Baseline) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 560x320, 465 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 90k tbn, 60 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2010-03-20 21:29:11
      encoder         : JVT/AVC Coding
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, mono, fltp, 83 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2010-03-20 21:29:11
[yuv4mpegpipe @ 0x21d8180] ERROR: yuv4mpeg can only handle yuv444p, yuv422p, yuv420p, yuv411p and gray8 pixel formats. And using 'strict -1' also yuv444p9, yuv422p9, yuv420p9, yuv444p10, yuv422p10, yuv420p10, yuv444p12, yuv422p12, yuv420p12, yuv444p14, yuv422p14, yuv420p14, yuv444p16, yuv422p16, yuv420p16 and gray16 pixel formats. Use -pix_fmt to select one.
Output #0, yuv4mpegpipe, to 'small_yuv420p12be.y4m':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: mp42isomavc1
    encoder         : Lavf56.18.100
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: rawvideo ([12][11]3Y / 0x59330B0C), yuv420p12be, 560x320, q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 7.50 fps, 7.50 tbn, 7.50 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2010-03-20 21:29:11
      encoder         : Lavc56.19.100 rawvideo
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 (native) -> rawvideo (native))
Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters ?): Input/output error
```

After that, I also tried to edit with an hexadecimal editor (bless) the small_yuv420p.y4m file. I replace `C420mpeg2` by `C420`, and the file was accepted by Chrome.
What does the number in `420p[number]` correspond to? It is not explained [there](http://wiki.multimedia.cx/index.php?title=YUV4MPEG2).
Is there any way to make `ffmpeg` output this kind of header files?

@SirDarius, thank you again for your help.

**The question**

(in case you forgot after this text blob)

How can I convert the `small.mp4` into a `small.y4m` file that has the same properties as the `mobile_qcif_7.5fps.y4m` file ?

Comment: arrrhh, the infamous fake ffmpeg which is really avconv. Please use a real FFMpeg. Static builds can be found from the ffmpeg.org website.

Comment: @SirDarius So I'm going to open a bug to the `ffmpeg` bug tracker to see what is going on.

Comment: Bug report opened at https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/4231#ticket

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, this answer assumes an official release of FFMpeg as downloaded from the official http://ffmpeg.org website. The version you are using is a wrapper program from the avconv fork that tries to spread the false information that ffmpeg is deprecated.

You have to use raw video, in a `yuv4mpegpipe` container format.

Additionally, to have the same framerate, the `fps` filter is needed, and the `-an` flag is used so the output video will not have an audio track.

The following command line should produce the desired result:

```
 ffmpeg -i small.mp4 -vf fps=7.5 -an -f yuv4mpegpipe -y small.y4m
```

Mediainfo gives the following result:

```
General
Complete name                            : small.y4m
Format                                   : YUV4MPEG2
File size                                : 10.8 MiB

Video
Format                                   : YUV
Width                                    : 560 pixels
Height                                   : 320 pixels
Display aspect ratio                     : 16:9
Frame rate                               : 7.500 fps
Color space                              : YUV
Scan type                                : Progressive
Compression mode                         : Lossless
```

Compare it to the original y4m file that you linked to:

```
General
Complete name                            : mobile_qcif_7.5fps.y4m
Format                                   : YUV4MPEG2
File size                                : 2.72 MiB

Video
Format                                   : YUV
Width                                    : 176 pixels
Height                                   : 144 pixels
Display aspect ratio                     : 4:3
Frame rate                               : 7.500 fps
Color space                              : YUV
Scan type                                : Progressive
Compression mode                         : Lossless
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer. I compiled `ffmpeg` from source (`ppa:jon-severinsson/ffmpeg` didn't work). I agre that the `mediainfo` output is now the same. There is something else though, and it still doesn't work with Chrome. To complete, I am trying to generate a video to play on Chrome as described there :  https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=318797
Does this particular snippet "(Only 420 would work -- 422 is _not_ supported)." makes any sense to you? Also, this can be tested easily on https://apprtc.appspot.com/

Comment: 420 here means a pixel format of YUV420. This is the default format created by ffmpeg here, but I'm not sure it is written correctly in the header, we have `C420mpeg2` while it seems the format mentions `C420` instead... might be a bug in ffmpeg... The sample y4m from your post doesn't even have a `C` parameter. You might want to try and hex-edit the resulting file to remove that parameter, or just the `mpeg2` part.

Comment: This https://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/2.5/yuv4mpegenc_8c_source.html#l00069 gives more insight as to what happens in the muxer... it might be worth it to try using different `-pix_fmt` values, see the output of `ffmpeg -pix_fmts`

Comment: Wow ! I edited the files :  Removing `C420mpeg2` works. Removing `XYSCSS=420MPEG2` still crashes Chrome. Removing both works ! I'll try your other suggestion also (I ultimately need to be able to automate it).

Comment: the X parameter is just a comment so it isn't interpreted either way, see http://wiki.multimedia.cx/index.php?title=YUV4MPEG2

Comment: I edited my question since the comments are limited in size. (Somewhat) shorter version : you were right `C420mpeg2` doesn't work, but `C420` works. I didn't get any result with `-pix_fmt`. Also, you mentioned the possibility of a `ffmpeg` bug; how likely is it to be a Chrome bug?

Comment: I'll use a simple script to remove the header `sed -i '0,/C420mpeg2/s//C420/' *.y4m `. So I'll accept your answer

Comment: On 2020-04-08 I get an error "codec not supported" but it works fine if I remove the `-c:v rawvideo`. Perhaps something has changed in FFmpeg meanwhile? Ideally the answer can be adjusted to match 2020 situation if this is indeed the case.

Comment: @Sander apparently, according to https://ffmpeg.org/faq.html, the yuv4mpegpipe format defaults to encoding to raw video, even though the `rawvideo` codec only supports decoding. Go figure :) It looks like an inconsistency in the CLI. Nevertheless, I'm updating the answer to remove the (now) invalid flag.